# Inno Setup - Detect when (un)installer is being run automatically by another process for a specific task

Tags: inno-setup

I am using this code in my custom `UninstallProgressForm` ([Custom Uninstall page (not MsgBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415457/custom-uninstall-page-not-msgbox#42550055)) to define a message after the uninstall (that does not have the original uninstaller messages):

```pascal
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  case CurUninstallStep of
    usPostUninstall:
      if not WizardVerySilent and UninstallSilent then begin
        MsgBox(CustomMessage('UninstallComplete'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
      end;
  end;
end;
```

I want to hide this message at determinate moment, at uninstall my previous version (if is present). For uninstall my previous version i am using this code: [How to detect old installation and offer removal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739317/how-to-detect-old-installation-and-offer-removal). I have modified the code of the previous link with this code to run the uninstaller if there is a previous version: [Executing UninstallString in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222356/executing-uninstallstring-in-inno-setup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a custom switch to the uninstaller, when you execute it to uninstall the previous version. Like `/UPDATE`:

```pascal
Exec(UninstallPath, UninstallParams + ' /UPDATE', '', SW_SHOW,
     wWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode)
```

And then check for the switch:

```pascal
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  case CurUninstallStep of
    usPostUninstall:
      if UninstallSilent and (not WizardVerySilent) and 
         (not CmdLineParamExists('/UPDATE')) then
      begin
        MsgBox(CustomMessage('UninstallComplete'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
      end;
  end;
end;
```

---

The `CmdLineParamExists` function comes from [Passing conditional parameter in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14392921/850848#14415103).