# Default Values to Inno Setup install

Tags: inno-setup

I have a group at work asking if there is a way to pass in values, either via command line or an ini value, that will "fill in" values that are normally provided by the user during install.  For example, if I have a drop down that the user can select they're installing the client, server, or both, they want a way to automate this so the user doesn't have to select anything.

Basically, they want to automate running the installer without actually showing the wizard panels and populating user values based on command line args or an ini file.

I know you can use ini files, but I don't think they're used for this reason. And I don't see any way that command args would be used.

Is there a way native to Inno Setup to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to set all the standard settings at once is to use an INF file via the [`/LOADINF` parameter](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline#LOADINF).

It is also possible to [extend this to custom page settings](http://vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Remembering_Custom_Page_Settings) if you wish (with cooperation by the setup author).

Comment: I think this may be the best approach.  So if I understand what I read through those links, if I have parameters like   gInstallArea : String;
  gShare : String ;          
  gSession : String ;           
  gSite : String ;                           
  gJMSEnv :String;          
  gSubdomain :String; Then I would need to define those as custom parameters in my ini file and then add that code to get those.  If we're loading with the ini file, I would set those variables with the data from the ini.  Is that correct?

Comment: I should note also that the majority of the data entered during an install is done in [CODE], not with Tasks or Components.  So these are all custom variables we gather through wizard pages and during install call {code:GetInstallArea} (for example) to set file paths and what not.  So while I did run with /SAVEINF, only a very small set of data was saved to the ini file because most of it is in set and retrieved in [CODE]

Comment: Yes, the ISXKB page covers custom `[Code]` settings.  Though you'll have to decide on your own whether to merely preload the settings or to skip over the custom pages entirely when `/LOADINF` is called, and you'll have to be careful of the settings being changed by your `NextButtonClick` handlers even when skipped.

Answer (score 2):

There are many command line parameters already included in Inno which you can use: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline

With them you can set task, directory, group, components, password etc etc.

If you need something special you can use your own command line parameters.
Use **GetCmdTail()** function to get cmd line parameters for setup or uninstaller.

As this is common question there are already some advanced parsers and methods like this one: 
[Is it possible to accept custom command line parameters with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618257/is-it-possible-to-accept-custom-command-line-parameters-with-innosetup)

I suggest you to use /SILENT parameter for not showing the setup forms together with e.g. /TASKS, /DIR and /COMPONENTS and some custom parameter.