# Add user defined command line parameters to /? window

Tags: inno-setup

With Inno Setup it is possible to add user defined command line parameters. When I use the `/?`, `/HELP` command the user defined parameters are not listed there. How can I add my commands with a description to the `/?`, `/HELP` window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inno Setup 6.0 supports [`HelpTextNote` message](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection), whose contents will be inserted into the `/HELP` box.

---

*In older versions:*

You cannot.

The help text is hard-coded and not customizable in any way. It's not even localized.

It is even displayed before any Pascal Script code ([`InitializeSetup`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup)) is executed, so there's even no room to install some fancy hook to modify the message box on runtime.

See the [`ShowHelp` function in the `SetupLdr.dpr`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/4ccbd8d869f1c862b9942e09e60d6bf232632e7a/Projects/SetupLdr.dpr#L282).

---

All you can do is to implement a custom switch (e.g. `/usage`) and handle it in the [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents).

---

Or, of course, you can modify Inno Setup source code and re-compile it. [It's open source.](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/license.txt)

---

A related question: [Is it possible to accept custom command line parameters with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3618257/850848#48349992)

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks for your help. So I will have to create my own help dialog.