# Passing a boolean as custom parameter

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I am currently trying to pass a `boolean` from a custom parameter but I can't figure out why the type mismatches and am not sure how to work around it:

```
WindowsAuthentication := ExpandConstant('{param:WinAuth|False}');
```

`WindowsAuthentication` is a `boolean` variable, and the parameter `WinAuth` is passed like this:

```
/WinAuth=True
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only strings. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35096481/243614) f.i. for how to convert to a boolean. E.g. `WindowsAuthentication := ExpandConstant('{param:WinAuth|False}') = 'True';`

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to test just for an existence of the parameter? `/WinAuth=True` does not look too user friendly to me.