# Conditional Registry entries with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want some registry entries to be written if two conditions are met:

- the installer is running in silent mode and
- I have some command line parameters present.

Is there a way to do this in the `[Registry]` section?

I have something similar in the `[Run]` section:

```
Filename: "{app}\AppWithParams.exe"; Parameters: "{code:BuildParams}"; \
   Flags: postinstall skipifsilent; \
   Description: "This program needs some parameters"
```

```pascal
[Code]
function BuildParams(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := Format('/p1="%s" /p2="%s" /p3="%s"', [
                      ExpandConstant('{param:p1|}'), 
                      ExpandConstant('{param:p2|}'),
                      ExpandConstant('{param:p3|}')]);
end;
```

I've seen that `[Registry]` entries can be made dependent of a `[Task]` but I need them only in silent mode so I think this approach won't serve me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck):

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; Check: ShouldCreateRegistry
```

```pascal
[Code]

function ShouldCreateRegistry: Boolean;
begin
  Result := WizardSilent and CmdLineParamExists('/CreateRegistry');
end;
```

- The [`WizardSilent`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardsilent) is built-in.
- For `CmdLineParamExists`, see [Is it possible to accept custom command line parameters with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3618257/850848#48349992).

---

Such trivial `Check` function can actually be inlined:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; \
    Check: WizardSilent and CmdLineParamExists('/CreateRegistry')
```